# Is shortening my url all via javascript doable?

Tags: javascript, url

I have a page which uses a the hash # to store some extra bit of info.
I want to add a button [short url]

which via javascript should

1. get the current url  (easy location.href)
2. pass it to some url shortener service (eg. bit.ly) etc.
3. get back the new url and show it in a textfield for the user to copy and paste (easy again)

It's point 2 that I don't know how to do (or if it is doable at all)

Note: that all of this should be solved on the client side nothing on my server side.

Comment: Approach this by looking for the services API; http://code.google.com/p/bitly-api/wiki/ApiDocumentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From http://code.google.com/p/bitly-api/wiki/ApiDocumentation#API_Key_Security

API Key Security

To ensure the absolute security of your API key, we suggest that you always make API calls **server-side**.

If it is absolutely necessary to call our API from **client-side** code, please keep in mind that **there is no way to positively ensure that your API key will not be discovered**. However, certain measures can be taken to mitigate this risk.

Answer (score 0):

Using the bit.ly API this should be cake:

http://code.google.com/p/bitly-api/wiki/ApiDocumentation#/v3/shorten

**/v3/shorten**

> For a long URL, /v3/shorten encodes a URL and returns a short one.

```
 $.getJSON("http://"+api_url+"/v3/shorten?longUrl=" 
    + encodeURIComponent(url) 
    + "&login=" + api_login 
    + "&apiKey=" + api_key 
    + "&callback=?", callback);
```

What you will ge back:

```
{
    "status_code": 200, 
    "data": {
        "url": "http://bit.ly/cmeH01", 
        "hash": "cmeH01", 
        "global_hash": "1YKMfY", 
        "long_url": "http://betaworks.com/", 
        "new_hash": 0
    }, 
    "status_txt": "OK"
}
```

Comment: Note that you will need the `callback` parameter when using this client-side.

Comment: It would seem so from their documentation

Comment: @hunter I don't believe that. Because than my login apiKey will be exposed to anybody who wants to see the source code of my js.

Comment: well, believe it or not... see the example js on their page. The login and apiKey are exposed.

Answer (score 0):

It would require shortener API to work over jsonp, which bitly does. I don't know about others. The alternative to jsonp would be a shortening proxy on your server passing the request to shortening service of your choice.

[bitly jsonp api](http://code.google.com/p/bitly-api/wiki/ApiDocumentation#Request_/_Response_Formats)

Comment: @Lambeder your solution requires authentication which, I believe, can not be done all on the clientside.